# How do I query for fields containing a given text in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
SELECT stuff REGEXP 'itunes' as is_itunes;
```

In this MySQL query, if "stuff" has the word "itunes" in it, it will mark it as itunes.

However, I want to say "begin with". How can I check for "begin with" instead of anywhere in the text?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

```
SELECT ... WHERE stuff LIKE 'itunes%';
```

Here `%` serves as a wildcard character, so this would match rows with the `stuff` field equal to any of `itunes`, `itunesfoo`, `itunes1`, ...

More info: [SQL LIKE Operator](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp) at *W3Schools*.

Comment: What if instead of `itunes` use placeholder? Is this correct `SELECT ... WHERE stuff LIKE ?'%';`

Comment: What does the % sign convey?

Comment: @Skynet, % is a wildcard that matches an arbitrary number of characters (including zero characters). So the example would match itunesstore, itunesUsername and itunes.

MySQL docs here, it's difficult searching Google for %! https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

Answer (score 8):

Add the caret symbol, it represents the beginning of the string:

```
SELECT stuff REGEXP '^itunes' as is_itunes;
```

However, `LIKE 'itunes%'` as suggested by Marc should be a lot faster, especially if your indexes are set up correctly.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT ... WHERE LEFT(stuff, 6) = 'itunes';
```

Answer (score 6):

For an indexed field it is much better to do:

`select ... where stuff >='itunes' AND stuff < 'itunet'`

This will not create a full table scan, and use the index.

Comment: this seems like the way to go for a known string prefix. can anyone else comment on performance, esp with a large table?

Comment: this looks like a relic left from mysql v3.23 days when all it had was myisam

Comment: I prefer this method because the string doesn't need to be escaped (\\) as it does with "like".

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT ... WHERE stuff REGEXP '[[:<:]]itunes';
```

Comment: another anser with no explanations at all.